# Is there a merchant that sells the Boar Skin resource?

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn

I'm in need of the Boar Skin resource, and am wondering if I can purchase it from a merchant, and if so which one in particular?  Or do I have to roam the wilds randomly killing boars until one drops this resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this item [cannot be purchased](http://horizonzerodawn.wikia.com/wiki/Boar_Skin).

The there is a quest that requires you to collect 4 boar skins called [luck of the hunt](https://m.au.ign.com/wikis/horizon-zero-dawn/Luck_of_the_Hunt), and while this quest is active, all boars drop boar skins. This means that if you kill 5 boars before collecting the skins, you can guarantee 5 boar skins.

Answer (score -1):

You have to hunt boars, no merchant is selling them. The same holds for all other animals.

- I've never seen it during my playthroughs
- "This rare resource is only found on Boars." ([Source](http://horizonzerodawn.wikia.com/wiki/Boar_Skin))

**Edit**: I just found out that this question is probably a duplicate and [already answered here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/326357/26705).

So there is one merchant in Meridian that sells crates that may contain animal parts.